# React app deployed to GitHub giving me a minified error #152

Tags: reactjs, webpack, deployment, github-pages

I am having a problem with my React application. I am trying to deploy the website to GitHub pages but I am getting this error:

```
Error: "Minified React error #152; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=152&args[]=u for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings."
```

The error is telling me to use the non-minified development environment, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Here is a link to my GitHub repository if you would like to check!

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/bennami/pomodoro2)

I am not sure how to solve this since this is the first time I try to deploy a website. I tried installing some dependencies like [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack), [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(compiler)), and Parcel to bundle my files into a readable JavaScript file, but my guess is that something is not being translated properly, meaning that there might be a syntax error somewhere in my code.

When running the Webpack dependency I did get a series of errors, that is why I installed some other libraries and loaders:

**Error on Terminal**

[image: Error terminal]

Comment: What do you mean by *"GitHub pages but Page"* (respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60971560/edit), not here in comments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the comments as suggested, but ended up using gh-pages instead of deploying via a docs directory on github, so it worked in the end. I have deployed other apps after that with comments and they work just fine.

So if you ever run into this, try gh-pages instead

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. The issue occurred wherever I deployed a production build to - locally or Firebase. I found that I had some comments in my render/return code and removing them solved this for me, as discussed at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8687.

Comment: I should have been more clear... that solves the initial minified error you had. I fixed without doing anything special with Webpack or Babel, so no idea about the second issue you had - i.e. building. Suggest you revert to where you first got the minified error, going through your React render/returns and removing ALL comments, then re-build/re-deploy. Best of luck!

Comment: thank you! i removed the comments, but ended up using gh-pages instead of deploying via a docs directory on github, so it worked in the end. I have deployed other apps after that with comments and they work just fine. thanks!